# Code::Blocks printf double with fixed precision in Windows

Tags: c++, printf, double, codeblocks, precision

I build and run the following code on two different operating systems:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    double d=1.123456;
    printf("%.5lf ",d);
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(5)<<d;

    return 0;
}
```

Code::Blocks in Ubuntu outputs: `1.12346 1.12346` (as expected)

Code::Blocks in Windows outputs: `0.00000 1.12346` (why `0.00000` !!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the printf call you indicate that you are passing a long double (with the 'lf') but only pass a double, the fact that it works on ubuntu is an accident rather than an indication that it is correct.

If you use %.5f rather than %.5lf it should work in both cases.

Comment: You are right it should be "%.5f" instead of "%.5lf", but is it works by accident in Visual Studio too?!! I need the real reason why it works fine. thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a printf("sizeof(double): %u, sizeof(long double): %u\n", sizeof(double), sizeof(long double)); and see if double and long double have different sizes, if they do then I would expect using the lf format specifier with a double to print the wrong result.

Comment: According to the [docs. I have to hand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) the lower case 'l' is essentially redundant (as of `c++11`) and assumes a `double` argument -- a `long double` argument requires an upper case 'L' as in `"%.5Lf"`.

Comment: `scanf("%lf",&d)` , but `printf("%f",d)` where d is double variable!!. 
According to cplusplus.com:
[link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) 
[link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)